# about Cartan's theorem

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, linear-groups, general-linear-group

theorem : Let $SL(n,\Bbb{C})$ be the group of matrices of complex entries and determinant $1$ then  $SL(n,\Bbb{C})$ is a regular submanifold of $GL(n,\Bbb{C})$.

proof : $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is a Lie group and $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ a closed subgroup. with  Cartan's theorem  $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is a regular Lie subgroup, in particular a regular submanifold.

Cartan's theorem : if $H$ is a closed subgroup of a Lie group G, then H is an embedded Lie group with the smooth structure (and hence the group topology) agreeing with the embedding.

> why $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is  a closed subgroup ? what is dimension of manifold $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ ?

Comment: The dimension of $SL(n,\Bbb C)$ is the vector space dimension of its Lie algebra, i.e., $n^2-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the map $\det\colon GL(n,\Bbb C)\longrightarrow\Bbb C$. It is continuous and therefore $\det^{-1}\bigl(\{1\}\bigr)$ is closed. But $\det^{-1}\bigl(\{1\}\bigr)=SL(n,\Bbb C)$.

And its dimension is$$\dim\mathfrak{sl}(n,\Bbb C)=\dim\left\{M\in\Bbb C^{n\times n}\,\middle|\,\operatorname{tr}M=0\right\}=n^2-1.$$

Comment: why $\det\colon GL(n,\Bbb C)\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ is continuous ? why $\dim\left\{M\in\Bbb C^{n\times n}\,\middle|\,\operatorname{tr}M=0\right\}=n^2-1$ ?

Comment: The determinant is continuous since it is a polynomial functions. And$$\dim\left\{M\in\Bbb C^{n\times n}\,\middle|\,\operatorname{tr}M=0\right\}=n^2-1$$because it is the dimension of the kernel of the trace and, by the rank-nullity theorem, the dimension of the kernel of a non-zero linear map from a finite-dimensional real vector space $V$ into $\Bbb R$ is $\dim(V)-1$.